# Check for duplicates while populating a string array

Tags: java, arrays, string, nullpointerexception

I'm having a hard time thinking about how should I implement the checking for duplicates while the string array with length of 5 is initially empty. Before adding an element in the array, I have to check first if it already exists in the array but because the array is initially empty (which means the five elements are null) it prompts an error, I think that is because I'm trying to compare the element (that I'm trying to add in the array) to null.

What I want to do is check if the the length of the array is less than the limit, check if the element that I want to add has no duplicate in the array. If it doesn't have a duplicate, then I'll add it in array, if it has a duplicate then I won't add it then I'll print a prompt message.

I am working on a project with multiple classes, here's the snippet of my code:

```
public class Collections {
    Guardian[] guardians;
    int count;
    
    final static int MAX_GUARDIANS = 5;

    public Collection () {
        guardians = new Guardian[Collection.MAX_GUARDIANS];
    }

    public void addGuardians (Guardian guardian) {

        if (this.count < MAX_GUARDIANS) {
            for (int i = 0; i < guardians.length; i++) {
                if (guardians[i].equals(guardian)) {
                    System.out.println("The guardian is already in the list!\n");
                } else {
                    this.guardians[this.count++] = guardian;
                    System.out.println("Guardian "+guardian.getName()+" was added to the list!");
                }
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("Maximum number of guardians in the list has been reached!\n");
        }

    }
}
```

Is it possible to compare the element that I'm planning to add to null?

Comment: Is order important?  If not just use a `Set`.

Comment: That's not a list, it's an array. If you were using a list you can just use list.contains()

Comment: @markspace no, order is not important, can I still check for duplicates if I use ```Set```? I'll look into that, thank you.

Comment: `} else { this.guardians[this.count++] = guardian;` No.  This is something students have trouble with, but doing it this way will add an element at the FIRST mismatch, without checking the rest of the array.  You need to check the whole array FIRST, with no else clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when you want to search for a duplicate, you have to search the whole array first.  Then if there's no duplicates, add an element after the `for` loop.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (guardians[i].equals(guardian)) {
                System.out.println("The guardian is already in the list!\n");
                return;   // <-- add this to EXIT when find a match
            }
         }
         // now that you've searched the whole list, 
         // you can add a new element
         guardians[count++] = guardian;
         System.out.println("Guardian "+guardian.getName()+" was added to the list!");
```

Comment: Still will cause a NPE

Comment: Alternative: `guardian.equals(guardians[i])`

Comment: I'm not seeing the NPE (though I didn't test this code).  Assuming there's only 5 guardians possible, it should work (I think there's only 5 in the movie).  If more than 5 guardians exist, the the assignment will throw IndexOutOfBoundsException when too many are added. @ChristopherSchneider

Comment: You assume your array is already populated. If `guardian[0]` hasn't been populated, you're calling `guardian[0].equals`, which is calling the equals method on a null reference.

Comment: No I'm using `count`.  If count is 0, the loop won't be entered at all.  If count is one, the first element is populated.  At least that's how I read it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a `HashSet<String>` to keep track of duplicates, and keep track of unique strings in an array.

Declare a hashset:

```
HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
// Or:
// Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
```

Check if a string is in a set with:

```
if(set.contains("Hello")) {
    // String is in the set
}
```

Add a string to a set with:

```
set.add("Hello");
```

Comment: this is Java not cpp oops

Comment: sincerest apologies

Comment: @kmeh if I use the ```set```, do i still have to use for loop to go through the list or the set function will do that automatically?

Comment: No, the array is now only used to store strings you know for sure are unique, and the set is there to help you identify unique strings.

So you have a string: you first check if the string is in the set. (Faster and easier than checking if string is in array). If it isn't, then it will not be in the array either. So you add the string to both the set and the array.

If the string IS in the set, then you know that it is also in the array. So you skip it.

Comment: @kmeh thank you so much! I'll try this in my code. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Use a list instead of an array to be able to check if it contains that guardian already.

```
public class Collections {
    List<Guardian> guardians;
    int count;

    final static int MAX_GUARDIANS = 5;

    public Collections () {
        guardians = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public void addGuardians (Guardian guardian) {
        if (guardians.size() >= MAX_GUARDIANS) {
            System.out.println("Maximum number of guardians in the list has been reached!\n");
        return;
        }
    
        if (guardians.contains(guardian)) {
            System.out.println("The guardian is already in the list!\n");
        } else {
            guardians.add(guardian);
            System.out.println("Guardian "+guardian.getName()+" was added to the list!");
        }
    }
}
```